# Cannot read property 'src' of undefined using a for loop with callback

Tags: javascript

I'm using this code:

```
function init(){
        var s = document.getElementsByClassName("seen");
        for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) tint(image_seen, 93, 196, 82, 255, function(d){
            s[i].src = d;
        });
    }
```

to set data urls for images with a classname. The function tint() does not return a value since to tint an image, it should be drawn to canvas (using callbacks). However, I get an error stating it cannot set `src` property of undefined. `console.log(i)` always returns `1`. (there is a total of 1 `img.seen` elements).

This drives me insane. What's wrong?

Comment: search, this is probably the #1 question about JS's for-loops

Comment: your all the functions refer to the same variable, and at the end of `for` loop this variable is equal to `s.length`. use closures to handle this. Look here for details - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example